# Build failure in xcode5 due to some toolchain related issue. Please answer

Tags: xcode5, toolchain

I am facing an issue while building my project. I couldn't find any relevant answer. This was not there earlier in release build. I later faced it after cleaning the project.

Error msg:

```
  (null):  
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:   
  file: -lboost_system is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

Can anybody please guide me

Thanks,

Comment: Show the complete linker command line.